# SQLite 'no such table' error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

I'm noob here but, why is it i'm getting this error?

I DO have a table named Team in an SQLite called Team.sqlite! Is there anything else I need to provide?

```
ERROR
---------------
2009-12-23 23:17:05.277 PitScout[6690:207] *** Assertion failure in -[Team addTeam], /Users/******/Desktop/PitScout/Classes/Team.m:90
2009-12-23 23:17:05.280 PitScout[6690:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error while creating add statement. 'no such table: Team''
2009-12-23 23:17:05.280 PitScout[6690:207] Stack: (
    30131291,
    2502464777,
    30215227,
    810772,
    16329,
    12146,
    20588,
    2753625,
    4667381,
    2753625,
    3160994,
    3169731,
    3164943,
    2858547,
    2766876,
    2793653,
    37420753,
    29916032,
    29912136,
    37414797,
    37414994,
    2797571,
    10780,
    10634
)
```

Comment: To answer this question, we'll need to know how you're opening the database and how you query the database, at the very least. Are you using Core Data?

Comment: try to open your database with some manager, for exmaple SQLite Manger Plugin for Firefox, or smth else. There you can enter your query. If your query will work there, it will work in your app, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use CoreData. Using SQLite directly is harder, requires more code, and is a waste of time unless you have very specific needs.
2. You say:

> I DO have a table named Team in an
>   SQLite called Team.sqlite! Is there
>   anything else I need to provide?

This doesn't make sense.  Are you saying you have a database named "Team.sqlite"?  Or do you have a table named "Team.sqlite"?   A table named "Team.sqlite" is not the same as a table named "Team".

How do you create the table?  I.e. what is the `CREATE TABLE` statement you are using?

Comment: Well I decided that Core Data was much more difficult for me, a mere beginner, and I have a FILE named Team.sqlite, and a table named Team in it. 
!

Comment: There might be a slightly steeper learning curve for Core Data, but give it a chance, especially if your project is for the learning experience. Once you learn how to use Core Data, it will make programming easier. Better to learn how to do it the "right" way from the start then having to learn a new way and unlearn bad habits from the old.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I restarted my project from scratch and it's fixed now. It turned out to be a problem with my SQL statements. Thanks everyone!

EDIT: The fix was regarding my SQL statements: I was calling for a table that DID exist, but I used:

```
NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SQLITE.sqlite"];
```

instead of:

```
NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Team.sqlite"];
```

which was actually caused by one of my earlier builds of the app.

My Teams.m was perfectly fine, however. This was actually within my SQLAppDelegate.m.

Comment: A heads up: SO is a Q&A site, not a forum. Your post here is marginally an answer to your question. To make it a complete answer, please edit this answer and explain the corrected statements and edit your question to add the broken statements so that others may learn from your problem. For future questions, make sure your answers truly answer the question. You can post more general statements (and questions for specific answers) as comments when you get 50 points (you can always post comments on your own questions).