# SQLite3 Integer Max Value

Tags: sql, sqlite, integer, ip

1. what is the maximum value of data type INTEGER in sqlite3 ?
2. How do you store ip address in database ?
3. What is attached ?
4. How to create table which belongs to a specific database using sql ddl?
5. What is this error about ?

> error while the list of system
>   catalogue : no such table: temp.sqlite_master 
>   Unable to execute statement

1. Does sqlite3 text data type supoports unicode?
   Thanks.

Comment: Do not expand the question with unrelated additional questions. Make specific questions that deal with specific problems and ask new questions. Let's not make this thread a tutorial on sqlite.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

1. Look at http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html Minimum is -(2<sup>63</sup>) == -9223372036854775808 and maximum is 2<sup>63</sup> - 1 == 9223372036854775807
2. I would think you should use a varchar
3. http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html
4. http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html
5. might be of help [SQLite 'no such table' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957196/sqlite-no-such-table-error)

in general check out the [sqlite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html)

Comment: For an 8 byte signed integer the max should be 2^63-1 or to put it another way the range should be -2^63 to 2^63-1

Comment: the most efficient way to store IPs in SQLite is `BLOB`, all ipv4's fit in BLOB(4) and all ipv6's fit in BLOB(16), but TEXT is the easiest way to store IP's in SQLite ^^

Comment: "_A storage class is more general than a datatype. The INTEGER storage class, for example, includes 6 different integer datatypes of different lengths. This makes a difference on disk. But as soon as INTEGER values are read off of disk and into memory for processing, they are converted to the most general datatype (__8-byte signed integer__)._" - for the people looking for wording used in the docs for #1.

Comment: I would argue that if you ever store anything that is going to be treated as immutable, short of an id field, it should be a string.  That is anything immutable that is independent of anything preceding or succeeding it

Answer (score 9):

> INTEGER. The value is a signed
>   integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8
>   bytes depending on the magnitude of
>   the value.
>
> The INTEGER storage class, for
>   example, includes 6 different integer
>   datatypes of different lengths. This
>   makes a difference on disk. But as
>   soon as INTEGER values are read off of
>   disk and into memory for processing,
>   they are converted to the most general
>   datatype (8-byte signed integer).

from http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Unless you have some other reason not to, you can store IP address using TEXT.

Comment: "*depending on the magnitude of the value*" How does one set this? **Edit:** I'm stupid, it will automatically determine the length needed. So you can just put in a huge number, it will see it's huge, and it will automatically use 8 bytes to store it! I was thinking along the lines of having to declare integer(8) or so... but no.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the second question:

You can store IP address in DB in 2 ways:

1. As a String. This is recommended
   as it will support both IPv4 and
   IPv6 and does not require no
   additional hassle with IP address
   conversions.
2. As an integer. IP is basically 4 bytes that can all be merged into one integer value. However, do you really want that? That will give you loads of pain converting it to/from string any time it is required.

Answer (score 2):

> - How do you store ip address in database ?

The easiest way is to store the string form (e.g., “`127.0.0.1`” or “`::1`”) since then you can read them manually and reparsing to an address structure (if you have to) is easy. SQLite likes strings (which use the TEXT type) and handles them efficiently.

Comment: Also, it's probably a mistake to try to break up an IP address into its component parts unless you're working for an ISP.

Answer (score 2):

> Does sqlite3 text data type supports
>   unicode?

Yes and no.

Yes in that SQLite lets you store `TEXT` data in UTF-8 or UTF-16.  (Use [PRAGMA ENCODING](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_encoding) to choose the internal format.)

No in that the built-in `LOWER` and `UPPER` functions only affect ASCII characters.  But you can [redefine functions](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) and [collations](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_collation.html) to add this support.  There's an [ICU extension](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/fileview?f=sqlite/ext/icu/README.txt) to SQLite that does this.