# Java Database AutoIncrement Primary Key Algorithm

Tags: java, sql

I have a sqlite database with an autoincrement primary key which is interfaced through java. 
For application reasons I can't use the auto generated primary key from the database so I need to create an id for each row in java.

So my question is, is there an algorithm out there for java that I could follow for creating unique Integer ids for a database.

I know I can just increment etc but I will need to use stuff like rollback, overflow and gap filling.

Comment: For "application reasons"? I'm not sure what exactly you mean, but maybe sqlite's sqlite3_int64 sqlite3_last_insert_rowid could help you and make it possible to use the database to generate your IDs... Have a look at the documentation: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html

Comment: Because of the design of our application, we need to be able to know the id for our record before its written to the database, sqlite3_last_insert_rowid would help if we allowed sqlite to manage id creation, basically I want a java implementation of the autoincrement algorithm used in databases

Comment: Do you really need gap filling? If not then the simplest approach would be to implement something like Oracle's sequences, i.e. a way of atomically obtaining a sequential id. Is your application load balanced (or will it ever be)? If so then I wouldn't do it in code.

Comment: The application is not load balanced, Gap filling may not be an issue but is there a maximum value that you can have for an Integer ID in sqlite?

Comment: It's big - see [SQLite3 Integer Max Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448284/sqlite3-integer-max-value) and [Limits In SQLite](http://sqlite.org/limits.html)

Answer (score 0):

according to your application requirement you may change primary key Integer to String and use can easily use java util class `java.util.UUID`. which  represents an immutable universally unique identifier (UUID). A UUID represents a 128-bit value.

In case application is having any persistence with integer primary key. You can write a function which produce sequence number. Logic behind it is , basically it needs to have current sequence. if not then make a call to db and fetch the max entry.

```
static Integer currentSequence=-1;
static Integer function primaryKeyGenerator(){
 if(currentSequence==-1){
   //Make a db call and get the max
  if(no data in table){
    currentSequence=1;
  }else
   currentSequence=rs.getInt(1);
 }
return currentSequence+=1;
}
```

Comment: This function will need to be synchronized if your application is multi-threaded

Comment: you absolutely r8. But its just a snippet. Idea how to implement.

Comment: sure - I guess the 'function' keyword should have alerted me that this is pseudo-code ;-)