# SQLite: Selecting numeric columns with values >= 2^31 fails

Tags: sqlite, node-sqlite3

According to the [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), numeric columns can store integers up to 8 bytes in size. However, I am having trouble actually selecting the values once they are stored:

```
create table x (a integer, b integer, c integer);
insert into x values ('2147483647', '2147483647', '2147483647');
select * from x;

+------------+------------+------------+
| a          | b          | c          |
+------------+------------+------------+
| 2147483647 | 2147483647 | 2147483647 |
+------------+------------+------------+
1 row in set

insert into x values ('2147483648', '2147483649', '2147483648');
select * from x;
```

**Nothing happens - no rows are returned**

```
select count(1) from x;

+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
| 2        |
+----------+
1 row in set

select substr(a, 1, 5) from x;
+-----------------+
| substr(a, 1, 5) |
+-----------------+
| 21474           |
| 21474           |
+-----------------
```

How can I retrieve the actual values properly, while retaining the integer data type? (Changing it to REAL or TEXT works as expected, but is there no other choice?)

Edit: I used Navicat for the demonstration above, but also ran into the issue with my actual application (using [node-sqlite3](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/)).

Comment: Selecting the count and substring is intended to show that the data has been stored, but cannot be retrieved in its original form.

Comment: Hi Ken, I think you are missing my point - SQLite claims that its integer datatype can store signed integers up to 2^63-1 bits in size, well above the examples I used here, but my problem is that I am having trouble retrieving the data once the values exceed 2^32-1.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+many+bits+in+1+byte https://www.google.com/search?q=maximum+8+byte+integer

Comment: [Ken White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62576/ken-white), this has been a waste of time all around - if you have no experience in SQLite I'll end this discussion here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448284/sqlite3-integer-max-value

Comment: Unable to reproduce using the sqlite3 shell -- your **Nothing happens - no rows are returned** case gives me both rows, with expected values.

Comment: Also, why use strings representing numbers instead of just the numbers directly? Since the columns have integer affinity they get converted anyways, but it looks weird.

Comment: Hi Shawn, thanks for the useful input, helped find the problem (outdated sqlite3 version in one of my components). Cheers